# Can a Linq query retrieve BLOBs from a Sql Database?

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, blob

Can a Linq query retrieve BLOBs from a Sql Database?
And how do they come out?

Comment: BLOB is a Oracle term, not a Microsoft SQL Server term. Refer to the specific column type to get a better answer (such as 'text' or 'image').

Comment: Oracle only eh? Someone'd better tell Microsoft! http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/sql/2000/reskit/part3/c1161.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ-To-SQL classes create properties of type System.Data.Linq.Binary for all binary and varbinary fields in SQL-Server. The Binary type has a .ToArray() method that returns a byte[], and its constructor can take a byte[].

Older versions of SQLMetal generated properties of type byte[], but the problem with these was that they failed in any joins. I think that's the main reason they replaced it with the IEquatable Binary type.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken LINQ to SQL teats BLOB as System.Byte[]
I recall that there was some problem with SqlMetal, it generated wrong type for BLOB, but MSVS dmbl designer should work.