# Entity SQL - Retrieves bytes data in chunks

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

The following code retrieves all bytes data at once.

I'm wondering how to access byte data stored in **chunk** using entity framework. Since files are so big (around 50MB), I want to send it to user by chunks as soon as I get partial bytes from database.

```
using (Entities context = new Entities(EntitiesConnectionString))
{
    byte[] data = context.MyFileTable
        .Where(item => item.FileId == 1)
        .Select(item => FileData)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289496/streaming-and-linq-blobs.

Comment: Not a duplicate, as that question is for LINQ to SQL. The answer may or may not be the same, but it's a different question.

Comment: This does not seem to be possible. Could not find any concrete evidence though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. EF and LinQ in general enumerates from a source. It will only ever yield complete objects from that source.

I have 2 possible solutions:

1. Query the data with your qualifying
   criteria that return a reference to
   what needs to be loaded, then stream
   in from there afterwards.
2. Write a wrapper class that
   implements IEnumerable, let this
   return your data along with a stream
   object you can then interrogate. You
   can then query this object, and have
   the stream available to you on the
   result set.1.

Option #1 is probably the easiest.1.

Comment: Thank you for the post. Do you know any web site that I can look up a sample code for either one of the solutions?

Comment: Here is the MSDN article for doing it via ADO.NET. So basically query only your keying info, then load the blob using this method independently. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4f5s1we0.aspx